# Machine learning - Structure of input data

Tags: python, pandas, neural-network, random-forest

I am trying out machine learning in python to predict future values. My data (X1, ... , X8, Y) can be seen in the attached figure.

[Description of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GqDy.png)

For testing, I have started by using sklearn RandomForestRegressor because the value that I am trying to predict is a float. My input data is originally a mix of data types (strings, floats, integers and True/False statements). All of which I have converted to numbers. Each string is represented my a unique integer. Each true/false is represented by either 1 or 0.

The examples I find online are usually either numbers (regressor problems?) or strings (classifier problems?).

Is this the correct approach for mixed input data types?

I am greatful for any input.

```
'''
X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8,Y
93,150,18,10,63,641.1024566,9,0,49.87777112
93,371,19,3,62,641.1024566,1,0,48.85200719
93,150,19,4,62,641.1024566,12,1,41.67165968
93,196,19,6,62,641.1024566,11,1,47.1851408
93,416,19,9,414,641.1024566,5,1,46.67225884
93,196,19,9,375,647.0940683,7,0,43.35530258
93,416,19,10,428,641.1024566,1,1,46.80047933
93,196,19,10,430,641.1024566,6,0,50.19832235
93,196,19,11,579,629.1192331,4,1,46.55482325
93,416,20,2,422,641.1024566,3,1,48.21090473
93,196,20,3,429,641.1024566,10,1,47.95446375
93,150,20,3,429,641.1024566,11,1,48.08268424
93,196,20,4,430,641.1024566,12,1,47.69802277
93,196,20,5,427,641.1024566,11,1,46.99281007
93,196,20,5,424,641.1024566,10,1,47.31336129
93,206,20,6,6,641.1024566,2,1,47.1851408
93,196,20,6,427,491.312163,11,1,35.66926303
93,196,20,9,430,641.1024566,4,1,47.24925105
93,416,20,8,362,641.1024566,8,1,48.08268424
'''


# Normalize input values
predictors = list(set(list(df1.columns))-set(target_column))
maximumPredictor = df1[predictors].max()
df1[predictors] = df1[predictors]/maximumPredictor
df1.describe().transpose()

df2[predictors] = df2[predictors]/maximumPredictor
df2.describe().transpose()

X = df1[predictors].values
y = df1[target_column].values
X_predict = df2[predictors].values


# Split data to evaluate the model with a portion of input data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=40)


# This is the regressor
regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=50,
                                  )

# Train regressor
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())

# Make a prediction from test data
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the strings repeat and you have encoded string 1 as 93 and string 2 as 94 and so on your approach is fine. Else you cannot use this approach, this resource might be useful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/339656/mix-of-text-and-numeric-data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all

> The examples I find online are usually either numbers (regressor
> problems?) or strings (classifier problems?).

This is more related to the thing(label) you are predicting. If you are predicting a category (which can be a string) from a finite set of possible categories, you are talking about **Classification**. If you are predicting a continuous value, where the value is anything from a continuous set - you are talking about **Regression**.

In your case Y seems to be the latter case, so Regression.

**Your question focuses on**: can I use strings as input data and combine it with the numeric data. This is actually not so easy.

You have transformed each unique string into a unique integer, but this will introduce unwanted relationships in the data. Eg:

- string 1 = 93
- string 2 = 94
- string 3 = 95

This implies that there is an ordering in the strings. The regression algorithm will try and use this ordering, but since it makes no sense it won't be able to find valuable information out of it.

Better solutions are:

- If the amount of different values for the strings is limited, Using a **dummy variable** could be an option.
- Use something like tf-idf, bag of words,... to find meaningful information in the strings, which allows you to compare the different strings with each other.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. By dummy variable; do you mean an additional column of data per string where the data row either has the name (1) or not (0)? My strings are unique names of things and there are 400 of them.

Comment: That's indeed what I was refering too.  (Also called one hot encoding) It depends on the size of your training data if it will be able to find interesting facts out of this. You could also look at bag of words / tf-idf, which will split the sentence up into a vector. Where the words in the sentence will be used instead of the sentence itself.